# Get a list of ALL facebook friends and their details

Tags: facebook, export

I have used a number of different applications to get what they claim to be a list of all my facebook friends into a .csv file or a similar format.  For some reason, these applications never export all of my friends and the total number of friends listed in the file is always over 100 less than the actual number of friends I have on facebook.  How can I properly export the names of ALL my friends and their details?